# Array is empty, but it keeps thinking there somthing inside

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

```
$result = usr::where("username", $username)->where("password", sha1($password))->get();

    echo $result;


    if(!empty($result)){
        echo " -WORKED :D";
    }else{ echo "FAILED D:"; }
```

Outcome is always '[] - WORKED :D' , the database isnt retruning anything, and the array is clearly empty, why is it thinking that theres something inside of the array?

EDIT:

OK, so I found a fix relatively quick, and I'm not sure why this works, but `empty()` dose not.

I just used `if(count($results) < 1){`  and it worked fine, can anyone explain why it wasn't working with the `empty()` condition?

Comment: check count instead of checking empty i.e,count($result) > 0 something like that

Comment: What does `var_dump($result);` show?

Comment: because $result is likely an object (of type Collection?) regardless of the records found

Comment: var_dump ($result) spits out all of Eloquent, so i don't touch that with a 40ft pole

Comment: [The documentation for `empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-returnvalues) is very clear about what values it considers empty. An Eloquent Collection of length 0 is not one of them.

Comment: then what do they class as empty?

Comment: It says in the link that I gave you above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it is not empty, you get a collection which is not filled with data.
Because a collection is a custom object, PHP does not know that it can be empty.

You need the [isEmpty](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_isEmpty) method from the Laravel framework.

Code line would be:

```
if(!$result->isEmpty())
```

Answer (score 1):

`get()` returns a Laravel Collection ([Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html)), not an array. You can check if its empty with `$result->isEmpty()` or with `$result->count() > 0`.

You can also use `$result->toArray()` to convert the collection into a normal php array.